How could I create a dynamic navigation structure with Nuxt 3?
I am trying to create something like this dynamically in Nuxt 3:
let paths = [
  {
    label: 'Page1',
    to: '/Page1'
  },
  {
    label: 'Page2',
    to: '/Page2',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Page2a',
        to: '/Page2/Page2a',
      },
      {
        label: 'Page2b',
        to: '/Page2/Page2b',
      },
      {
        label: 'Page2c',
        to: '/Page2/Page2c',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Page3',
    to: '/Page3',
  }
]

I am trying to get to a place where if pages are added to the pages directory, they will automatically be added to the array (which is going into a navigation tree).
I have tried using useRouter().getRoutes() but it doesn't display pages as children which is the main issue.
Any help is much appreciated! :)

So, if you have a directory named Page2, and then put Page2a.vue inside of it, isn't it solving your issue? Otherwise, you have the dynamic routes (where you could use [parent]/[parent][child].vue)but I do not see the other approach not covered by those two.

You can try useRouter().options.routes
